# Streaming large data from RPi to iPhone

Tags: pi-3, communication

I would like to transmit a large files e.g. video from Raspberry Pi to iPhone. I read that might be possible via starting Websocket server on Raspberry Pi and connecting iPhone to it. Is there any better/efficient way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to stream, or send files? Define "better" for this purpose, please. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Hey, I want Raspberry Pi to e.g. record HD Movie with attached camera. Then I want to transfer this movie to companion app. Because HD movie will be quite large I can't transfer it via BLE. Its simply too slow. My idea is to use websocket's over WiFi from hotspot what will be run on iPhone. I'm wondering if thats correct approach in terms of efficiency (how quick movie will be transferred), battery usage on RPi and ease of implementation of such solution.